# Edit has been in review que for over 2 hours

Tags: support, suggested-edits

[This](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/203767) edit has been stuck there for over two hours. It's a very good edit that improves the question but it's only shown to me in the past 2 hours. I think it's stuck somehow. Can someone look at it?

Comment: Super User's slow on weekends. It's not unreasonable for a suggested edit to take 2 hours to get through the queue. It's gone through now; I don't think it was stuck, there just wasn't much activity.

Comment: @nhinkle Huh, I thought that it'd be faster on weekends. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you look at the [quantcast data](https://www.quantcast.com/superuser.com) for Super User you can see the weekly dip on weekends. Our internal analytics reflect the same trend in terms of the number of suggested edits.